# Where to find particular library files for cygwin(64bit)

Tags: cygwin, repository, static-libraries, windows-7-x64

I need some particular library files for Cygwin (64-bit). Where can I find them online? The files are `libgcc_s.dll.a`, `libgcc.a,libcygwin.a`. I do not want to reinstall Cygwin again, I just want the individual library files. Does anyone know of a repository with these library files? 
I am using a Windows 7 (64bit) setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to reinstall Cygwin again.  But you do need to run the [setup utility](https://cygwin.com/install.html), choose a mirror, and select the packages containing the libraries you need.  It will install them for you in the necessary places.  Really, it's not hard.